# proper use of c++ standard queue

Tags: c++, visual-studio, queue

I am using Visual Studio 2013.
I am using the following as part of my code:

```
#include <queue>
#include <curses> // pdcurses for mvprintw function
using namespace std;
typedef unsigned short ushort;    
struct xy{
    int x;
    int y;
};    
void move(ushort length, queue<xy>& test);    
int main() {
  // ...
}    
void move(ushort length, queue<xy>& test) {
    queue<xy> coord;    
    if (length <= test.size()) {
        coord = test.pop();
        mvprintw(coord.y, coord.x, "  ");
    }    
    // ...
}
```

If I were to use the queue I made (which does not allow for templates), setting it up to use that struct as its type, it works fine. However, I want to make use of a templated queue so I can use queues of other types as well. But when I use the c++ standard queue in the way given above, I get the following error:

```
error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'void' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\queue(101): could be 'std::queue<xy,std::deque<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>> &std::queue<_Ty,std::deque<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>>::operator =(std::queue<_Ty,std::deque<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>> &&)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=xy
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\queue(43): or       'std::queue<xy,std::deque<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>> &std::queue<_Ty,std::deque<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>>::operator =(const std::queue<_Ty,std::deque<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>> &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=xy
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(std::queue<xy,std::deque<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>>, void)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=xy
1>          ]
```

Am I missing something simple? I don't see why it seems to think the pop function returns a void type. Does the queue not use pop() for what I think it does? Or is the error in how I am using the Queue in my code?

Comment: *"I don't see why it seems to think the pop function returns a void type."* -- Because, it does. Have you read documentation for the function?

Comment: Additionally to what @BenjaminLindley said, you are trying to take the top element from the queue and set the queue equal to it?  That doesn't make any sense as you can't convert `xy` to `queue<xy>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you meant to declare `coord` to be of type `xy`, not `queue<xy>`.

Popping from `std::queue` indeed returns nothing; it simply removes the front element. If you want the front element, call `front` and *then* pop.

```
coord = test.front();
test.pop();
```

Comment: This is correct, it was meant to be type xy. Typically in my experience pop functions for queues return a value as well as removing that element, and I don't see the reason why they would return a void.

Comment: @user2403132: Two reasons. One is that a core principle of C++ is that you don't pay for what you don't use.  So, if I don't care what the front value of a queue is when I pop it, I should not have to incur the cost of the copy that would come in returning it by value. Two, the copy would possibly cause an exception to be thrown, weakening the exception guarantee provided by the underlying container's `pop_front` function. This is highly undesirable.